# Surface plot [0,2]×[0,]→ℝ^3

Tags: plotting

Please, given my inexperience, can someone help me to plot this function
F: [0,2]×[0,]→ℝ^3.
(,)↦((+cos/4)sin,(+cos/4)cos,(−)sin/4).

The function represents a rigid bar of length L which moves around a cylinder of radius R and by changing position (: angle in sexagesimal degrees, and =angular velocity of  is constant), so simultaneously describes a spiral in the horizontal plane and a helical trajectory on the cylinder.(image).

So regarding the goal of the animation, I was thinking of limiting the animation to  €(0,1...n...90'); n€N.

The bar in its motion describes a surface in ℝ^3 and this surface subtends a volume closed between the horizontal plane and the suface.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Image: [image]

Comment: Please can you clarify what you want regarding the animation / volume / angular velocity? That whole part doesn't really make sense and you have some spelling and grammar mistakes.

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D` is used to plot parametrized surfaces.

Comment: @Dap can you format your equations with TeX? It's really not clear in the current format if you mean Cos[/4] or Cos[]/4.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Möbius strip. Sometimes it's easier to do these by just rendering a point cloud instead of a surface. I've also got the bar going around too. Remove the export and replace `Animate` with `Manipulate` if you want to change $\theta$ interactively:

```
L = 3;
R = 1;
f[θ_, s_] := {(R + s Cos[θ]/4) Sin[θ], (R + s Cos[θ]/4) Cos[θ], (L - s) Sin[θ]/4}
pts = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 2 π}, {0, L}}], 5000];

circ = Line[Table[f[θ, 0.0], {θ, 0, 2 π, 0.05}]];
anim = Animate[
   Show[ListPointPlot3D[f @@@ pts, BoxRatios -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> 1.75*{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
    Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{f[θ, 0], f[θ, L]}], Gray, 
      circ}]
    ], {θ, 0, 2 π}
   ];
Export["test.gif", anim]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
However, I would like to be able to represent the phenomenon differently.
The objective is the didactic representation of a physical phenomenon, such as that of a rigid bar subject to a constrained motion (in the drawing), through mathematics.
This in order to demonstrate how physical reality can be described through mathematics, and by studying its function, predict its effects.

Comment: @Dap I've added the bar.

Comment: Thank you Flinty, thank you very much